# P4: how to find files in a case insensitive manner?

Tags: perforce, case-sensitive

Say a file is known to P4 as Foo.cpp

p4 files -e -m 100 //XXX/YYY/...foo.cpp*

(note the lower case f) can't find it. Has anyone overcome this issue?

EDIT: the place I am running the command from does not have a local p4 checkout so going through the file system is not an option here.

Comment: Not beautiful, but: 'p4 files -e //XXX/YYY/... | grep -i foo.cpp | head -n 100'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able, I would highly recommend going through the trouble (thanks to Linux-dependency hell) of installing P4Search. It will give you the case-insensitive searching power you seek, but it will also save you hours and hours of time down the road.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.1/user/p4searchnotes.txt

Comment: I was not aware of this tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Perforce Broker to rewrite the command, but this would only be practical if all of your files started with an upper case letter.

Some examples of using the broker to rewrite commands are here:

http://www.perforce.com/blog/120727/customising-perforce-using-p4broker-rewrite-command

The simplest long term solution may be to move to a case insensitive server, but note that this is not a trivial process.

If this is something you want to do, I strongly recommend you contact 'support@perforce.com' for advice and more information.

You might also find this KB article helpful:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3081

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: thanks for the comment but I picked the answer above ;)